# ImageLabeler getting NullPointerException but no arguments null

Tags: java, tensorflow, machine-learning, nullpointerexception

I've been trying to build an ML image classifier. When I try to instansiate it, I get a NullPointerException:

```
private void processImage(Bitmap image) {
    LocalModel localModel = new LocalModel.Builder().setAssetFilePath("model.tflite").build();
    CustomImageLabelerOptions customImageLabelerOptions = new CustomImageLabelerOptions.Builder(localModel)
            .setConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
            .setMaxResultCount(5)
            .build();
    try {
        ImageLabeler imageLabeler = ImageLabeling.getClient(customImageLabelerOptions);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stack trace shows this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:1)
  at com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MultiFlavorDetectorCreator.create(com.google.mlkit:vision-common@@17.0.0:1)
  at com.google.mlkit.vision.label.ImageLabeling.getClient(com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-common@@18.0.0:2)
```

I can't find out anything about Preconditions.checkNotNull. I added

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.1.0'
```

(whatever the heck this is) to my gradle just to make sure, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, but seems to be resolved after adding additional dependencies...

```
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling-custom:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:18.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.android.odml:image:1.0.0-beta1"
```

Also, make sure that noCompress is set in module build.gradle file, in its `android {}` section.

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}
```